# How to remove a language/Quality Profile from SonarQube project settings

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-ops

I can <kbd>+ Add language</kbd> via the according button but I do not see a way to remove one:

[image]

This is for v8.7.1 but the same applies for v6.6. My account is in the *sonar-administrators* group on both instances (but on the latter I can't even add a language.)

The [documentation for Project settings](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/project-settings/) doesn't mention anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s actually two other ways to “disable” a language:

- Creating another Quality Profile by coping the build-in one (instead of extending it) and disabling all rules.
- Changing the file suffixes associated to a language to something invalid. For instance you could set the file extension for sql to .foobar. Because none of your SQL file will have a .foobar file suffixes, they won’t be analyzed. You can change this settings from your project dashboard > General Settings > Languages > File suffixes.

Source: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-turn-off-analysis-for-specific-languages/21671